# Gradually increase the height of the form

Tags: c#

i have an alert form that appears at right corner of my screen and i want to increase it's height gradually,like some anti virus alerts !
i try this code but didn't work, i guess i must use degates but i do't know how and on which evaen

```
private void AlertForm__Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int h = 377;
    int Curr = 0;
    while (Curr < h)
    {
        this.Height = Curr;
        Curr++;
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

could you please help me?

Comment: You have to do it outside the AlertForm__Load method, because you increase the height until 377 and then the Load method is finished and the Form will be displayed with a Height of 377 directly. Maybe use a Timer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing the height, but that lowers the bottom of the form not moves the top up.

You should also avoid tying up interactivity with `Thread.Sleep` use a timer as otis suggested.

A form which doesn't respond for at least 3.77 seconds while it "scrolls" up is just going to be irritating.

```
private void AlertForm__Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myTimer.Enabled = true;
}

const int h = 377;
const int quietTop = 0;
int Curr = 0;

private void myTimer_tick()
{
    this.Height = Curr;
    this.Top = quietTop - Curr;
    Curr++;

    if (Curr >= h)
        this.myTimer.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: i want to show this changing to users but it shows the finall result of height or top

Comment: @ozzy_mra that's because it's in the form load event and hogging the UI thread. It needs the UI thread to be able to draw the updates, including changing the forms position.